# C++ FILE without writing to disk

Tags: c++, ios, file-io, memorystream

I'm using a library that has quite a few functions that write to a `FILE` but none that seem to conveniently dump the same data to an object in memory.  Is there any way to create a `FILE` object (or override it) that stores the data in memory instead of writing to disk -- I'd like to avoid the performance hit of opening/writing/reading from files over and over again.

**UPDATE:** per Rob's suggestion, trying stringstream:

```
ss.put(c);

std::string myval = ss.str();

printf("Value: %s\n after writing: %i length %lu\n",myval.c_str(),c, myval.length());
```

But, now trying to get the data (binary) out of the stringstream has me stuck -- how do I grab the binary data I've been adding?

Comment: Only for completeness sake, I mention [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/). `stringstream` won't solve OP's problem, because he is tied to `FILE`. If he could modify his library, he could use `stringstream`.

Comment: @Rob - my goal was to avoid modifying the source of the library (to avoid conflict when upgrading, etc), but I do have the option.  I think I may take this path, since the other solutions are looking more low-level than my C skills right now.

Basically, I need to replace or augment a function that right now is using `fputc` -- I'll be using `put` from `stringstream` instead, right?

Comment: Don't be afraid to use `fmemopen` or `open_memstream`. They look like perfect solutions for you. But, if you do want to use `stringstream`, see my answer.

Comment: neither function is available to me on iOS, so I'd be stuck doing `mmap` stuff -- another thing I'm not comfortable with yet!

Comment: Your's is a perfect question for an interview!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beside the already mentioned GNU's `fmemopen()`, which is known in POSIX as [open_memstream](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html)<strike>, similar solution can be obtained combining `mmap()` (using MAP_ANONYMOUS) or any other OS-specific function that returns a file descriptor to a block of memory, and `fdopen()`.</strike>

EDIT: that was wrong, mmap doesn't create a file descriptor.

Comment: Great answer.  My limited C skills are making me wary of getting in this deep, though -- see my comment to Rob on the original post.  May be able to get away with just a small modification to the original library.

Comment: How did you get a file descriptor from mmap that could be used with fdopen? I'm trying to get a FILE pointer to a mmap'd location in memory that doesn't have a backing file.

Comment: @featherless You're right, `mmap` doesn't create a file descriptor. I was thinking of `shm_open` when writing that, but `shm_open`'s file descriptor isn't allowed in `fdopen`. Thank you for pointing out the error!

Answer (score 5):

The GNU libc has, e.g., `fmemopen` which will give you a `FILE *` that writes to memory. Try `man fmemopen` on your Linux system for details.

I suspect (but do not know for sure) that `fmemopen` is a wrapper that orchestrates the `mmap`/`fdopen` approach mentioned by @Cubbi.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of modifying your library, you could use C++ streams instead of C FILE streams.

If your old library function looked like this:

```
void SomeFun(int this, int that, FILE* logger) {
  ... other code ...
  fprintf(logger, "%d, %d\n", this, that);
  fputs("Warning Message!", logger);
  char c = '\n';
  fputc(c, logger);
}
```

you might replace that code with:

```
void SomeFun(int this, int that, std::ostream& logger) {
  ... other code ...
  logger << this << ", " << that << "\n";
  // or: logger << boost::format("%d %d\n") %this %that;
  logger << "Warning Message!";
  char c = '\n';
  logger.put(c);
  // or: logger << c;
}
```

Then, in your non-library code, do something like:

```
#include <sstream>    
std::stringstream logStream;
SomeFun(42, 56, logStream);
DisplayCStringOnGui(logStream.str().c_str());
```

Comment: EDIT: put code in original question for better formatting

I've got it working, up to a basic point.  The problem I'm hitting now is getting the data out -- it's binary data.  Right now, I have:
`ss.put(c);
    
    std::string myval = ss.str();
    
    printf("Value: %s\n after writing: %i length %lu\n",myval.c_str(),c, myval.length());`

The length() call gives me a value the increases accurately, but I'm stuck trying to get the data out -- the c_str gives me a `const char*` with a length of 4 -- missing most of the binary data

Comment: If the data that the library returns is binary (that is, potentially has `'\0'` characters embedded in it), then you won't be able to use `printf("%s", ...)` to access it. Are you just trying t display that data? Or do you need to pass it to another function? You can access the data byte-by-byte like this: `myval[i]`. Or you can pass a pointer to the data like this: `MyFunc(myval.data(), myval.length())`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac OS X or iOS you don't have access to fmemopen. I've open sourced a solution here:

http://jverkoey.github.com/fmemopen/

Answer (score 0):

Consider mounting a [`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) and have the application write to it. Of course this is *nix only.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Snaipe/fmem appears to be a portable `fmemopen` in C. It gives you FILE you can write to and when you done you get a `void*` that points to the memory where you data is.